# Establish connection between IBM MQ and ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic, ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I'm new in Websphere MQ and trying to learn integration between ActiveMQ and IBM Websphere MQ. I couldn't find any proper tutorial or couldn't understand how to do it.

**What I want to do:** I want to trigger a XML to JSON transformed message from IBM MQ to ActiveMQ. From MQ Explorer, I was successful in creating "Initial Context", located the .jar file. When I'm trying to create a "connectionFactory", its giving me [an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivucF.png).

Also I read [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1211_eswarachary/1211_eswarachary.html) about `jndi.properties` but can't figure out where to keep the `.properties` file. Though I want to keep things dynamic (want to ignore the `.properties` file) but it might be helpful for me someday.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did you tag it esql?

Comment: What is "MQ Explorer"? Are you open to writing your own client to do this work or even using something like Camel?

Comment: @JoshMc since I used esql for transformation of data from XML to JSON

Comment: @JustinBertram I use MQ Explorer (by IBM) to manage the Queues of MQ. It can create JMS Queues which can be used in IIB. There is video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3DgwISsLxD8) which is using MQ Explorer with PowerExchange

Comment: You should click esql and read it and note it is not the right tag.

Comment: @JoshMc apologies, I've corrected it. Can you please help me?

Comment: From what I can tell MQ Explorer is only useful to create JMS administered objects (i.e. connection factories and destinations) and configure other internal details about IBM MQ. It doesn't appear possible to define any kind of process to move messages to another JMS provider (e.g. ActiveMQ) much less perform arbitrary transformations on the messages which are moved. Why are you trying to use MQ Explorer for this task? Why not just write a JMS client to do the work?

Comment: @JustinBertram it was just for learning new thing, as shown [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1211_eswarachary/1211_eswarachary.html)

Comment: IIB has the ability to interface with JMS providers via JMS nodes, but MQ Explorer can only generating the binding information for IBM MQ as a JMS provider.  Based on the link you provided it describers creating a file called `jndi.properties` and placing it in the the "Message Broker classes directory", the article is from 2012 when IIB was called "WebSphere Message Broker" so one would conclude the same step would be taking for the "IIB classes directory".  The error you provided has a "Details" button, does this show any further info?

Comment: Note that screen shots are not the recommended choice on StackOverflow, the error message would not be searchable for future SO users either via the SO search box, or via other search engines like Google.  Even if you can't cut-n-paste the text, it is so short I would recommend you just type it in your question, you can add \`\`\` before and after to get mono-spaced font formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using esql, I'm assuming you are using IIB. The first step to get the message from IBM MQ is either use a MQInput or MQRead node.

Once done, you do your transformation with ESQL (apparently) or any other compute node.

To post to ActiveMQ, it's a different story. IIB doesn't have any "native node" to do it, so in my opinion the best solution is to use a Java Compute node (don't forget to correctly import the ActiveMQ jars into IIB shared-classes) and do it from there.

But for the MQExplorer and the bindings (factory, destination, ...) it is used by client application to connect to IBM MQ. I don't see any reason to have it in your case (if you use it to connect from IIB, please stop immediately)

I feel like you have a lack of knowledge of the tools you are using, so I would recommend you to get back to the basics (or I miss understood your question). In addition, you have not even mentioned IIB in your question, which is the main component in your problem, so next time try to detail your question with as much information as you can.

Comment: Thanks for the answers... All I wanted was to exchange message message from ActiveMQ to Websphere MQ and vice versa. I was able to do so after some more digging on internet.

Comment: @DipanjanDas Would you be able to provide a reference to what you found and/or what you got working?

Comment: @Clearly - Drop me a mail at dipanjan.19932008@gmail.com. I'll happily explain you what I wanted, how i did it 